# Send a SOAP request, where to start?

Tags: c#, .net, soap

I need to send a SOAP request to a URL. But i find this harder then i thought it would be.

The request that i have to send is:

```
string bla = "" +
"<?xml version='\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
        "<soap:Body>" +
            "<ns1:sendNotificationResponse" +
              "xmlns=\"http://notification.services.adyen.com\"" +
              "xmlns:ns2=\"http://common.services.adyen.com\">" +
            "<notificationResponse>[accepted]</notificationResponse>" +
            "</sendNotificationResponse>" +
        "</soap:Body>" +
    "</soap:Envelope>";
```

I've been given an URL: https://ca-test.adyen.com/ca/services/Notification?wsdl

The problem is, is that I'm not sure how to go on from here. Can i simply just send a request to that URL? Or do I have to import the WSDL somehow first?

I've found a lot of examples on the net, but I couldn't really make sense out of most of them. Some were even out dated, because they were still using: **Microsoft.Web.Services3**

So in short, I'm kinda clueless on what I exactly have to do here and how. I simply want to send that 'SOAP' message...

Comment: Have you tried to add `Service reference` or `Web Reference` in your VS?

Comment: Try this link on how to create or consume a web service: http://www.kevingao.net/wcf-java-interop/wcf-client-and-wcf-service.html

Comment: @L.B No, this is all really new to me. I do see "Add Service Reference" but not "Add Web Reference". I'll try to add the "Service Reference" first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by adding a service reference to the endpoint URL you've provided in the question. Then you can call the web method as you would call a normal method, just off the client object. Step-by-step below:

1. Right-click references, select add service reference
2. Enter URL to add service reference
3. In code instantiate new client and use as below:

> ```
> ServiceReference1.NotificationPortTypeClient client = new ServiceReference1.NotificationPortTypeClient(); 
> client.sendNotification(...);
> ```

**Edit**

Looking at the web service in more detail, it looks as though the SOAP request you have included in the question is the response that would be sent back by the url when you had invoked the method - not the request you would send to the web service to invoke the method.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be easier to add a web service reference in Visual Studio? What you get are "stub" classes that allow you to communicate with the web service using normal classes and methods - you don't need to care about the SOAP messages being sent or whatnot.

To add such a reference, you can select the "Add Service Reference" context menu item. Depending on the type of service, you will need to press the button in the lower left of the service reference dialog (in German this is called "Erweitert", which would translate to "Enhanced" or "Extended"). The next dialog also has a button at the lower left in the "Compatibility" section to add a ".NET 2.0 style web service reference".

One of the two should help you.

If you need to send the request manually, you would send a POST request to the web service's URL adding the XML code as the requests body.

Comment: I've added the WSDL as a reference. It showed me in the dialog that i has one function 'sendNotification'. I guess that's what i need. I now have "ServiceReference1" under "Service References". I guess that's good right? --- Next thing i have to do is actually use it. Any idea how i can do that? --- ServiceReference1 service = new ServiceReference1(); --- Doesn't do the trick.

Comment: There should now be a `ServiceReference1` namespace. So if you enter `ServiceReference1.` and wait for the code completion popup to appear, you will see some classes. The one you need should end with "Client". For example "Service1Client".

Comment: As Richard found out, the line should be `ServiceReference1.NotificationPortTypeClient client = new ServiceReference1.NotificationPortTypeClient()`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding "how to send soap messages": Dependant of the used procotol (http, jms, even smtp), SOAP messages can be for instane sent even from the command line, via telnet, curl etc..

So regarding your question: Sorry for the generic answer, but it depends of the used ws-framework.

Regarding the WSDL: The WSDL acts as the contract/base for the implementation, so in your case (assuming that your SOAP-message is already valid according to the schema in the WSDL) making explicit use of the WSDL is not really necessary.